# Android ant build: proguard can't find referenced method in class ViewConfigurationCompatFroyo

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

I'm very short on time here, so I truly hope someone here has a clue how to fix these:

```
[proguard] Warning: android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompatFroyo: can't find referenced method 'int getScaledPagingTouchSlop()' in class android.view.ViewConfiguration
[proguard] Note: org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory: can't find dynamically referenced class java.util.ConcurrentNavigableMap
[proguard] Note: org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory: can't find dynamically referenced class java.util.ConcurrentSkipListMap
[proguard] Note: there were 2 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
[proguard]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[proguard] Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
[proguard]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[proguard]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[proguard]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the options
[proguard]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' and/or
[proguard]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
```

I already tried adding multiple things:

```
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
```

and also (for the jackson errors):

```
-libraryjars /Libraries/Joda/joda-time-1.6.2.jar
-libraryjars /Libraries/stax2-api-3.0.0.jar
-libraryjars /Libraries/jsr311-api-0.8.jar
-libraryjars /Libraries/httpmime-4.0.1.jar
```

Anyone have a clue what i'm missing in my proguard.cfg for these references? Or potentially some tips on how to investigate / resolve it more generally?

I brought it down from 472 warnings to just these, mostly by adding the dontwarn statements:
    -dontwarn java.awt.**,javax.security.**,java.beans.**,javax.xml.**,java.util.**,org.w3c.dom.**

EDIT: Migrated to Answer

Comment: This is still an "unanswered" question. Can you answer your own question and then accept that answer. That would remove it from the "unanswered" list.

Comment: I have migrated your edit to your answer now you just have to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

```
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2
-dontwarn android.support.v4.view.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

-dontwarn java.awt.**,javax.security.**,java.beans.**,javax.xml.**,java.util.**,org.w3c.dom.**
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited my post above to display the answer.

Found it.

These seemed to help.

```
-dontwarn **CompatHoneycomb
-dontwarn **CompatCreatorHoneycombMR2
-dontwarn android.support.v4.view.**
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

-dontwarn java.awt.**,javax.security.**,java.beans.**,javax.xml.**,java.util.**,org.w3c.dom.**
```

Comment: I have migrated edit to answer now you just need to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your proguard configuration file.

```
-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.** { 
    *; 
}
```

You do not need to obscure 3rd party libraries.